# Rectify this Error:GetLastError 0x13d

Tags: c++, c, winapi, getlasterror, formatmessage

In this sample,the dwerror is `10045L`.but this code returns 0x13d value as error.
How to get the format message?Please have a look into it.

```
TCHAR lpMsgBuf[512];
if(!FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
    NULL,
    dwError,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
    0, NULL ))
{
    wprintf(L"Format message failed with 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look up what error code `0x13d` means, for example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x13d == 317 == `ERROR_MR_MID_NOT_FOUND`.
The message for the error you're trying to find doesn't exist in SYSTEM.
Maybe your error originate from a specific **dll** or **driver**.
If you know which dll\driver try to abtain it handle and specify `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` instead of `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` and supply the handle as the source in the call to `FormatMessage`.

And besides that if you use `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` you should declare a variable of type `LPTSTR` like `LPTSTR pMsg;` and pass it to FormatMessage as **`(LPTSTR)&pMsg`** and when you're done with it use `LocalFree(pMsg)` to release the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you say FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, you do not need to allocate more than a pointer. Then you pass a pointer to that pointer in lpBuffer. So try this:

```
TCHAR* lpMsgBuf;
if(!FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
    NULL,
    dwError,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
    0, NULL ))
{
    wprintf(L"Format message failed with 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}
```

And do not forget to call LocalFree

or you allocate the buffer yourself:

```
TCHAR lpMsgBuf[512];
if(!FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
    NULL,
    dwError,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR) lpMsgBuf,
    512, NULL ))
{
    wprintf(L"Format message failed with 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}
```

Also, try this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int alloc(char** pbuff,unsigned int n)
{
*pbuff=(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
}

int main()
{
char buffer[512];

printf("Address of buffer before: %p\n",&buffer);

//  GCC sais: "cannot convert char (*)[512] to char** ... "
//  alloc(&buffer,128);

//  if i try to cast:   
alloc((char**)&buffer,128);
printf("Address of buffer after:  %p\n",&buffer);

// if i do it the right way:
char* p_buffer;
alloc(&p_buffer,128);
printf("Address of buffer after:  %p\n",p_buffer);


return 0;
}
```

It does not make sense to try to change the address of a variable. That is probably why your code does not work.